# Connect an external camera to QField data collection

Tags: qfield

Is it possible to connect a point and shoot camera to my Samsung A7 Lite via bluetooth and have pictures attached to an attribute form?

Comment: Since you can connect GPS-devices via Bluetooth, I don't see why this shouldn't work, either. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?